# Modify an array and push to form another array

Tags: ruby

What is a better way than this:

```
X = %w(a b c)
Y = %w()
  X.each do |x|
    Y << "good_" + x
  end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
%w(a b c).map{|x| "good_#{x}"}
```

Answer (score 3):

collect method on array will do

```
Y = X.collect{|e|'good_'+e}
```

OR

directly

```
Y = %w(a b c).collect{|e|'good_'+e}
```

Answer (score 1):

to have them both defined on same line:

```
y = ( x = %w[a b c] ).map { |i| 'good_%s' % i }

y
=> ["good_a", "good_b", "good_c"]

x
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```